# How to get noticed when ScrollBar is appeared on Panel? VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, panel

I just want to resize a certain Control in a Panel at the certain point when the vertical ScrollBar of the Panel is appeared due to need of scrolling.

Panel.Resize or Panel.SizeChanged is not exactly what I wanted because it is called whenever the size of the Panel is changed rather than exact point when the inside of the Panel size is changed due to the Panel get a ScrollBar width.

Comment: It is typically not a good idea to do this.  Most users find it annoying/distracting to have controls change their size just because a scrollbar appeared.  Usually you just keep the controls out of the scrollbar area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ClientSizeChanged event will fire.  You could detect that the scrollbar became visible with code like this:

```
Private Sub Panel1_ClientSizeChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Panel1.ClientSizeChanged
    If Panel1.VerticalScroll.Visible Then
        '' etc...
    End If
End Sub
```

Beware that the event will fire multiple times.  If you do anything to rearrange controls to make the scrollbar invisible again then beware that you'll induce a good deal of highly visible flicker.

Since there normally isn't anything that the *user* could do to resize controls, only your code does that, the much better alternative is to actively prevent the scrollbar from showing in the first place.